# Track Shoutcast streams in Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics, shoutcast, internet-radio

Is there a way to track Shoutcast streams in Google Analytics?

So for example, each time someone listens to the stream, it records that as a pageview in Google Analytics?

I suspect it might result in modifying the Shoutcast server code, but I'm wondering if anyone has done this before, or could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**2020 Edit: SHOUTcast v2 log tail feature has a bug which prevents a stream of log entries from working.  Therefore, this service is no longer available.**  I would delete this answer, but it's accepted on the question so I cannot.

<del>Yes, this is possible.  I offer a free service, the [AudioPump Analytics Connector](http://audiopump.co), relays your SHOUTcast listener data in real time to Google Analytics for tracking as page views.  No modification to SHOUTcast is necessary.</del>

<del>It also tracks individual metadata, allowing you to compare tracks and programs to see which are performing better.  (I like to look at the exit page percentage to determine what content to purge from rotation, and which to keep.)</del>

Comment: You sound like you use it, is it a paid for service? I did look at it myself, but there was no info on if it was a fee based service.

Comment: @mattauckland It's actually a service I created, and it is free.

Comment: Cool sounds good, it never mentioned pricing on the site, so I was a little reluctant to sign up. I'll give that a go. Thanks :)

Comment: Hey Brad. Have you tested your service on the new Shoutcast server release. I know currently that mAirList listener count feature is broken since this release, and I'm in talks with mAirList and Shoutcast (via DrO) to resolve the issue. I've not gone live 24/7 just yet, so haven't sign up yet.

Comment: @mattauckland The Analytics Connector has never worked properly with any SHOUTcast v2 release due to a bug with idle connection handling in the SHOUTcast server's log tail functionality.  I have simply blacklisted v2 servers.  I have not tested recently, but my bug reports of the issue years ago have gone unanswered.  Now that Radionomy is running the show, perhaps it has gotten some development love, but I haven't recently tested.  What specific version are you using?

Comment: I'm running 2.4.7.256 which is the very latest build. DrO on the Winamp/Shoutcast forums is the best guy to talk to. My server is live tonight (UK) at http://live.sumoradio.uk:8000/

Comment: I'm adding a follow up comment. I've since developed a script and cron job that grabs the data from the live Shoutcast server(s), and stores it in a database. This works better for me, as I can track countries, cities, listening session length, and even referring source. As I'm an awesome guy, this is basically how I did it. I use CURL to poll the server, reading the Shoutcast XML data. But on the v2 servers you need the admin password to do this. Maybe that could help get AudioPump up and running again.

Comment: Brad, I'm wondering how to access the Google analytics reports based on the ID provided. I've looked and looked, but came up empty in obtaining this information.

Comment: @mattauckland - I'm very interested in seeing your script and cron. I run a liquidsoap script to my shoutcast server for Hawkwynd Radio, and would really like to see what you've built to get some data from my listeners activities.

Comment: @mattauckland - I'm logging listener connections with a node.js script I wrote that uses mongodb to store the data much like a logging script. It captures geo location, connection time, ip address info. Now, I am working on the reporting scripts to be able to slice/dice the data by region, connection time, etc. Is this something you have built?